# Trouble with Spring Qualifiers two beans of type "org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"

Tags: java, spring

I must be missing something easy.  Here is a snippet of my Spring configuration XML:

```
<bean id="queueDestination" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="TestQ" />
</bean>

<bean id="topicDestination" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="TestTopic" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="queueDestination" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTopicTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsTopicConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="topicDestination" />
</bean>
```

and here is the code the tries to autowire it in:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("jmsQueueTemplate")
private JmsTemplate jmsQueueTemplate;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("queueDestination")
private Destination queueDestination;
```

I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'publish': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate com.vulab.publishsubscribe.Publish.jmsTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [jmsQueueTemplate, jmsTopicTemplate]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

Please help me understand what I am missing.

**I have a feeling this has nothing to do with @Autowire or @Qualifier.  I think it is because I have two beans defined with the "org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" class.**

Thanks.

Comment: The qualifier for the `Destination` is invalid in your example, it should be `queueDestination` and not `queue`. Can you post the full stacktrace please?

Comment: I have tried lots of combinations including "queueDestination" as my qualifier.  It doesn't work.  Full stack trace included in the above post.

Comment: Make sure you have to correct `@Qualifier` annotation. The one from the Spring package and not the one from the `javax.inject` package.

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is coming from the code snipper above? You may have another class that does not have the qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

I compared your code to [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/). I don't think you need the `<qualifier/>` property in your beans. Instead, you can use the bean ID as your value in the `@Qualifier` annotation.

Also, make sure to register AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor at the top of your applicationContext.xml.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

---

[Here's another tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/), and if you scroll down you'll find an example with `@Qualifier`.

Comment: I saw that example.  The main difference is I can't use the "name" property because "org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" doesn't have one.

Comment: You don't need a "name" property. That property is actually irrelevant to the example. The relevant pieces of information are the respective bean IDs for the two Person instances, and the @Qualifier annotations in the Java code. These two steps, along with registering `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, should be enough to do the job.

Comment: I have also tried matching the Qualifier name to the bean's ID and that isn't working either.  I am missing something simple.

Comment: You have to register the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean in your configuration file.

Comment: Also get rid of the `<qualifier value="...">` properties in your beans.

Comment: I tried adding "<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>" to my XML config file, removed the <qualifier> tags, and made the Qualifier annotations match the IDs of the respective beans.  Still getting the same error. :-(

Comment: You didn't have it before? It should be at the top of your file. Follow the second tutorial I linked (under the horizontal rule) step-by-step! There should be no problems.

Comment: Your AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is equivalent to "<context:annotation-config />" which I have had in my configuration file.

Comment: Oh ok, that works too. If you do it that way (I prefer it as well) make sure you have the spring-context namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, while I am still learning about `Spring JMS`, I found that

```
<bean id="..." class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"> : 
</bean>
```

Just should be defined once, same as `ConnectionFactory`, at least in the same context.

My solution was to define just one `JmsTemplate` without *defaultDestination*:

(using the post sample)

```
<bean id="jmsQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Then just need a POJO to send messages:

```
import javax.jms.Destination;
public class MySender {
    private final JmsTemplate template;
    private Destination queue;

    public ShortcodeRelaySender(JmsTemplate template, Destination queue) {
        this.template = template;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void send(String msg) {
        template.convertAndSend(queue, msg);
    }
}
```

and then define two beans, one per queue destination:

```
<bean id="queueSender" class="my.package.MySender">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jmsQueueTemplate"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="queueDestination"/>
</bean>

<bean id="topicSender" class="my.package.MySender">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jmsQueueTemplate"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="topicDestination"/>
</bean>
```

I don't know if this is the best way to resolve the issue, but It works for me to send more than one destination in the same context.

Maybe helps someone else :)

BR.